# Why is javascript ignoring second if statment?

Tags: javascript

I was working on some codes for beginners and I come across a task to calculate a tip, given a bill, using a function and an array. When I see the result I see that 555 was applied with the x 0.15 even though it the `bill` isn't a number between 50 and 300. Why is that?

```
const calcTip = bill => {
    if (bill >= 50 || bill <= 300){
        return bill * 0.15
    } else {
        return bill * 0.20
    }
};
const bills = [125, 555, 44];
const tips = [calcTip(bills[0]), calcTip(bills[1]), calcTip(bills[2])];
console.log(tips[1])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the check

```
if(bill >= 50 || bill <= 300)
```

you are multiplying `bill` to 0.15 when it is greater than 50 OR less than 300. This mean always.

You meant

```
if(bill >= 50 && bill <= 300)
```

Translating in English it sounds like *"If the bill is greater then the minimum AND it is less than than the maximum..."*.

Comment: Due to the condition bill>=50 and having the || operator, anything value greater than 50 always is true and it will never check the condition bill <= 300. As suggested by @Roberto, you need to replace || with && operator. you can check the short circuit evaluation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR#short-circuit_evaluation